# Using lasmerge in QGIS 2.8.3 is not working: "...instance has no attribute"

Tags: qgis, merge, lidar, las, lastools

Every time I try running `lasmerge` tool from LASTools within QGIS, I get the following error message:

> Algorithm lasmerge starting...
>   lasmerge instance has no attribute 'addParametersApplyFileSourceIdsCommands' See log for more details

I have already installed the 2.8 LASTools fixed provided by the QGIS guide.
I have checked nothing above [input LAS/LAZ file] nor have I included anything in the additional command line parameters.

I am trying to merge 4 different LAS files.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to QGIS 2.10? I have tested `lasmerge` from the _Processing_ plugin version 2.10.2 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

See in GitHub, [LAStools QGIS_toolbox, the README.txt](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/tree/master/QGIS_toolbox) file. It says:

> For QGIS 2.8 all is great. For small bug fixes copy and replace
>   the scripts of the "QGIS_2_8_toolbox_bug_fixes.zip" archive into
>   whatever path corresponds in your installation to this one:
>   C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\lidar\lastools

I tried it :)